# How I cam fix error in installing pyminzip

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, unzip

When I try to install pyminzip I see this

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pyminizip
Collecting pyminizip
  Downloading pyminizip-0.2.4.tar.gz (258 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 258.7/258.7 kB 155.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyminizip
  Building wheel for pyminizip (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pyminizip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyminizip
  Running setup.py clean for pyminizip
Failed to build pyminizip
Installing collected packages: pyminizip
  Running setup.py install for pyminizip ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyminizip did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pyminizip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyminizip

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: The error tells you that you need to install Visual C++ 14.0 or greater from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/. `pyminizip` needs it to compile code since it's not a prebuilt wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It's explicitly said :

```py
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Please install Microsoft Visual C++ compiler to make it work

Comment: What do I need to download (I already have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: @wowlikon open the Developer Command Prompt and use it to run `pip`. Alternatively, you need to run the developer command `bat` file to set up your command line to have all the correct environment variables so that `pip` can find your compiler.